# Reading files in C++ with Cmake on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: c++, cmake

I'm trying to read some files in a C++ program.

```
ifstream di("../data/dipendenti.txt");
...
ifstream di("../data/clienti.txt");
...
ifstream di("../data/prodotti.txt");
```

The files are located in a **/data/** directory and the executable file is in a **/bin/** directory.
This is my CMake file:

```
include(CheckCXXCompilerFlag)

CMAKE_MINIMUM_REQUIRED(VERSION 3.5)
PROJECT(Azienda CXX)

CHECK_CXX_COMPILER_FLAG("-std=c++14" COMPILER_SUPPORTS_CXX14)
IF (COMPILER_SUPPORTS_CXX14)
    ADD_COMPILE_OPTIONS("-std=c++14")
ELSE()
    MESSAGE(FATAL_ERROR "Compiler ${CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER} has no C++14 support.")
ENDIF()

INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES("${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/include")
set(CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/bin)

FILE(GLOB_RECURSE SRCS ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/*.cpp)

ADD_EXECUTABLE(azienda ${SRCS})
```

The problem is that when I execute the program it appears like the files are empty or the program can't read them.
I tried to move the **/data/** folder inside the **/bin/** one (and I modified the code inside the .cpp file removing *../data/* ) but nothing changed.

Can someone explain to me what am I doing wrong?

**Edit:** as requested I now added the whole code. I know the code is not written perfectly, but that is my 1st time using C++ (and professor want us to use a lot of different features).
While all the files were in the same directory everything was working fine. Since I started to use CMake and put the files in differents folders the program stopped reading files.

**/include/header.hpp**

```
#ifndef HEADER
#define HEADER

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>
#include <fstream>

enum statop { Nuovo, Usato };

using namespace std;

class Persona {
    string nome;
    string cognome;
    string cf;
    string mail;
    string telefono;
    string indirizzo;

    public:
        Persona(string s1, string s2, string s3, string s4, string s5, string s6) : nome(s1), cognome(s2), cf(s3), mail(s4), telefono(s5), indirizzo(s6) {
            //cout << "Oggetto Persona creato correttamente." << endl;
        }   //costruttore
        Persona() = default; //costruttore vuoto
        ~Persona() {
            //cout << "Oggetto Persona distrutto correttamente." << endl;
        }   //distruttore
        string getNome();
        void setNome(string s);
        string getCognome();
        void setCognome(string s);
        string getCf();
        void setCf(string s);
        string getMail();
        void setMail(string s);
        string getTelefono();
        void setTelefono(string s);
        string getIndirizzo();
        void setIndirizzo(string s);

        virtual string getNominativo();
        virtual int getLivello();
};

class Dipendente : public Persona {
    string matricola;
    string ruolo;
    float stipendio;
    string settore;

    public:
        Dipendente(string s1, string s2, string s3, string s4, string s5, string s6, string s7, string s8, float f1, string s9) : Persona(s1, s2, s3, s4, s5, s6), matricola(s7), ruolo(s8), stipendio(f1), settore(s9) {
            //cout << "Oggetto Dipendente creato correttamente." << endl;
        }   //costruttore
        Dipendente() = default; //costruttore vuoto
        ~Dipendente() {
            //cout << "Oggetto Dipendente distrutto correttamente." << endl;
        }   //distruttore
        string getMatricola();
        void setMatricola(string s);
        string getRuolo();
        void setRuolo(string s);
        float getStipendio();
        void setStipendio(float f);
        string getSettore();
        void setSettore(string s);

        string checkCF(string q, int i, Dipendente* d);
        string getNominativo() override;
        int getLivello() override;

};

class Cliente : public Persona {
    string codiceCliente;
    int numeroOrdini;

    public:
        Cliente(string s1, string s2, string s3, string s4, string s5, string s6, string s7, int i1) : Persona(s1, s2, s3, s4, s5, s6), codiceCliente(s7), numeroOrdini(i1) {
            //cout << "Oggetto Cliente creato correttamente." << endl;
        }   //costruttore
        Cliente() = default; //costruttore vuoto
        ~Cliente() {
            //cout << "Oggetto Cliente distrutto correttamente." << endl;
        }   //distruttore
        string getCodiceCliente();
        void setCodiceCliente(string s);
        int getNumeroOrdini();
        void setNumeroOrdini(int i);

        void checkCF(string* q, int* i, int* num_d, Cliente* c, Dipendente* d);
        string getNominativo() override;
        int getLivello() override;
};

class Prodotto {
    string codiceProdotto;
    string nomeProdotto;
    string marca;
    int quantita;
    float prezzo;
    statop stato;

    public:
        Prodotto(string s1, string s2, string s3, int i1, float f1, statop s4) : codiceProdotto(s1), nomeProdotto(s2), marca(s3), quantita(i1), prezzo(f1), stato(s4) {
            //cout << "Oggetto Prodotto creato correttamente." << endl;
        }
        Prodotto() = default; //costruttore vuoto
        ~Prodotto(){
            //cout << "Oggetto Prodotto distrutto correttamente." << endl;
        }
        string getCodiceProdotto();
        void setCodiceProdotto(string s);
        string getNomeProdotto();
        void setNomeProdotto(string s);
        string getMarca();
        void setMarca(string s);
        int getQuantita();
        void setQuantita(int i);
        float getPrezzo();
        void setPrezzo(float f);
        string getStato();
        void setStato(statop s);
        string getNominativo();


};

//NAMESPACE
namespace indirizzo_non_formattato {
    void stampaIndirizzo(Cliente c);
}
namespace indirizzo_formattato {
    void stampaIndirizzo(Cliente c);
}

void checkExistsCP(string* s, int* i, int* pos, Prodotto* p);

void checkExistsCC(string *s, int* i, int* pos, Cliente* c);

void checkExistsCD(string *s, int* i, int* pos, Dipendente* d);

void infoProdotto(int i, Prodotto* p);

void infoCliente(int i, Cliente* c);

void infoDipendente(int i, Dipendente* d);

//FUNZIONI LAMBDA TIMES E DIVIDE
constexpr auto times = [](auto n1, auto n2) { return n1 * n2; };
constexpr auto divide = [](auto n1, auto n2) { return n1 / n2; };

constexpr float IVA();

void calcIva(int i, Prodotto* p);

bool effettuaOrdine(int i, int j, Cliente* c, Prodotto* p);

template <typename X>
string visualizza(X* a, int i);

bool CF_Corretto (string &str);

#endif
```

**/src/source.cpp**

```
#include "header.hpp"

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>
#include <fstream>
#define DIM 16


using namespace std;




// *** FUNZIONI ***
void checkExistsCP(string* s, int* i, int* pos, Prodotto* p) { //controlla l'esistenza di un codice prodotto
    bool foundOne = false;

    do {
        for (int j = 0; j < *i; j ++) {
            if(s[0].compare(p[j].getCodiceProdotto()) == 0) {
                foundOne = true;
                *pos=j;
            }
        }

        if (!foundOne) {
            cout << endl;
            cout << "Codice inserito inesistente. Reinseriscilo: " << endl;
            cin >> *s;
        }
    }while(!foundOne);

}

void checkExistsCC(string *s, int* i, int* pos, Cliente* c) { //controlla l'esistenza di un codice cliente
    bool foundOne = false;

    do {
        for (int j = 0; j < *i; j ++) {
            if(s[0].compare(c[j].getCodiceCliente()) == 0) {
                foundOne = true;
                *pos=j;
            }
        }

        if (!foundOne) {
            cout << endl;
            cout << "Codice inserito inesistente. Reinseriscilo: " << endl;
            cin >> *s;
        }
    }while(!foundOne);
}

void checkExistsCD(string *s, int* i, int* pos, Dipendente* d) { //controlla l'esistenza di una matricola
    bool foundOne = false;

    do {
        for (int j = 0; j < *i; j ++) {
            if(s[0].compare(d[j].getMatricola()) == 0) {
                foundOne = true;
                *pos=j;
            }
        }

        if (!foundOne) {
            cout << endl;
            cout << "Matricola inserita inesistente. Reinseriscila: " << endl;
            cin >> *s;
        }
    }while(!foundOne);
}

void infoProdotto(int i, Prodotto* p) {
    string temp_p;
    int pos;

    cout << "Inserisci il codice del prodotto da visualizzare: " << endl;
    cin >> temp_p;

    checkExistsCP(&temp_p, &i, &pos, p);

    cout << "Prodotto: " << p[pos].getCodiceProdotto() << " - " << p[pos].getStato() << endl
         << p[pos].getNomeProdotto() << ", " << p[pos].getMarca() << " (" << p[pos].getPrezzo() << " euro)" << endl
         << "Pezzi in magazzino: " << p[pos].getQuantita() << endl;

    cout << endl;

}

void infoCliente(int i, Cliente* c) {
    string temp_c;
    int pos;

    cout << "Inserisci il codice del cliente da visualizzare: " << endl;
    cin >> temp_c;

    checkExistsCC(&temp_c, &i, &pos, c);

    cout << "Cliente: " << c[pos].getCodiceCliente() << " - " << c[pos].getMail() << endl
         << c[pos].getNome() << " " << c[pos].getCognome() << " - " << c[pos].getTelefono() << endl
         << c[pos].getIndirizzo() << endl
         << "Numero ordini effettuati: " << c[pos].getNumeroOrdini() << endl;

    cout << endl;

}

void infoDipendente(int i, Dipendente* d) {
    string temp_d;
    int pos;

    cout << "Inserisci la matricola del dipendente da visualizzare: " << endl;
    cin >> temp_d;

    checkExistsCD(&temp_d, &i, &pos, d);

    cout << "Dipendente: " << d[pos].getMatricola() << " - " << d[pos].getTelefono() << endl
         << d[pos].getNome() << " " << d[pos].getCognome() << " - " << d[pos].getMail() << endl
         << "Settore: " << d[pos].getSettore() << " - Ruolo: " << d[pos].getRuolo() << endl
         << d[pos].getIndirizzo() << endl
         << "Stipendio: " << d[pos].getStipendio() << endl;

    cout << endl;

}

constexpr float IVA(){
    return 22.0;
}

void calcIva(int i, Prodotto* p) {
    float iva = IVA();
    string temp_s;
    int pos;

    cout << "Inserisci il codice del prodotto da calcolare senza IVA: " << endl;
    cin >> temp_s;

    checkExistsCP(&temp_s, &i, &pos, p);

    //utilizzo auto per calcolare nel momento di compilazione il tipo dell'attributo prezzo
    auto prezzo=p[pos].getPrezzo();

    //utilizzo le funzioni lambda times e divide
    auto sub = divide(times(static_cast<float> (prezzo), iva), 100.00);
    prezzo=prezzo-sub;

    cout << "Il prezzo senza iva del prodotto " << temp_s << " e': " << setprecision (2) << fixed << static_cast<float> (prezzo) << endl;
    cout << endl;
}

bool effettuaOrdine(int i, int j, Cliente* c, Prodotto* p) {
    //i -> numero clienti, j -> numero prodotti
    string temp_p;
    string temp_c;
    int pos_p, pos_c;

    cout << "Inserisci il codice prodotto da acquistare: " << endl;
    cin >> temp_p;

    checkExistsCP(&temp_p, &j, &pos_p, p);

    cout << "Inserisci il codice del cliente che ha effettuato l'ordine: " << endl;
    cin >> temp_c;

    checkExistsCC(&temp_c, &i, &pos_c, c);

    if(p[pos_p].getQuantita() > 0) {
        p[pos_p].setQuantita(p[pos_p].getQuantita()-1);
        c[pos_c].setNumeroOrdini(c[pos_c].getNumeroOrdini()+1);
        cout << "Ordine effettuato correttamente." << endl;
        cout << "Sara' spedito a: ";
        indirizzo_formattato::stampaIndirizzo(c[pos_c]);
        cout << endl;
        return true;
    }
    else {
        cout << "Non ci sono piu' pezzi disponibili del prodotto scelto." << endl;
        cout << "Nessun prodotto spedito in ";
        indirizzo_non_formattato::stampaIndirizzo(c[pos_c]);
    }
    cout << endl;
    return false;
}


bool CF_Corretto (string &str){
    string CF;
    constexpr bool controllo[DIM]={1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,1};
    bool temp = true;

    for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++)
        CF[i] = (toupper(str[i]));

    for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++){
        if(CF[i] >= 'A' && CF[i] <= 'Z' && controllo[i]);
     else if(CF[i] >= '0' && CF[i] <= '9' && !controllo[i]);
     else
            temp = false;
    }
    return temp;
}

// *** SVILUPPO FUNZIONI PERSONA ***

string Persona::getNominativo() {
    return "\nNome: " + getNome() + "\nCognome: " + getCognome();
}

int Persona::getLivello() {
    return 0;
}

string Persona::getNome() {
    return nome;
}

void Persona::setNome(string s) {
    nome=s;
}

string Persona::getCognome() {
    return cognome;
}

void Persona::setCognome(string s) {
    cognome=s;
}

string Persona::getCf() {
    return cf;
}

void Persona::setCf(string s) {
    cf=s;
}

string Persona::getMail() {
    return mail;
}

void Persona::setMail(string s) {
    mail=s;
}

string Persona::getTelefono() {
    return telefono;
}

void Persona::setTelefono(string s) {
    telefono=s;
}

string Persona::getIndirizzo() {
    return indirizzo;
}

void Persona::setIndirizzo(string s) {
    indirizzo=s;
}

// *** SVILUPPO FUNZIONI DIPENDENTE ***
string checkCF(string q, int i, Dipendente* d) {
    bool foundOne=false; //nel caso diventi true a fine ciclo mi ripeterà il controllo per essere sicuro che l'utente non abbia inserito nuovamente un CF uguale ad un altro
    string temp_q = q;

    while(!CF_Corretto(temp_q)){
        cout << "Codice Fiscale Errato" << endl;
        cout << "Inserire di nuovo il Codice Fiscale: " << endl;
        cin >> temp_q;
    }


    if(i == 0) {    //se i == 0 vuol dire che questa è la prima persona in assoluto che inseriamo e non ci saranno quindi cf uguali
        return temp_q;
    }
    else {
        do {
            foundOne=false;
            for (int j = 0; j < i; j ++) {
                if(temp_q.compare(d[j].getCf()) == 0) {
                    foundOne=true;
                    cout << "Codice fiscale gia' presente! Inseriscine uno nuovo: " << endl;
                    cin >> temp_q;
                    while(!CF_Corretto(temp_q)){
                        cout << "Codice Fiscale Errato" << endl;
                        cout << "Inserire di nuovo il Codice Fiscale: " << endl;
                        cin >> temp_q;
                    }
                }
            }
        }while(foundOne);
    }
    return temp_q;
}

string Dipendente::getNominativo() {
    return Persona::getNominativo() + "\nMatricola: " + getMatricola();
}

int Dipendente::getLivello() {
    return 2;
}

string Dipendente::getMatricola() {
    return matricola;
}

void Dipendente::setMatricola(string s) {
    matricola=s;
}

string Dipendente::getRuolo() {
    return ruolo;
}

void Dipendente::setRuolo(string s) {
    ruolo=s;
}

float Dipendente::getStipendio() {
    return stipendio;
}

void Dipendente::setStipendio(float f) {
    stipendio=f;
}

string Dipendente::getSettore() {
    return settore;
}

void Dipendente::setSettore(string s) {
    settore=s;
}

//*** SVILUPPO FUNZIONI CLIENTE ***

void checkCF(string* q, int* i, int* num_d, Cliente* c, Dipendente* d) {
    bool foundOne=false; //nel caso diventi true a fine ciclo mi ripeterà il controllo per essere sicuro che l'utente non abbia inserito nuovamente un CF uguale ad un altro
    string temp_q = *q;

    while(!CF_Corretto(temp_q)){
        cout << "Codice Fiscale Errato" << endl;
        cout << "Inserire di nuovo il Codice Fiscale: " << endl;
        cin >> temp_q;
    }


    do {
        foundOne=false;
        temp_q = checkCF(temp_q, *num_d, d); //controllo che non sia un CF di un dipendente

        for (int j = 0; j < *i; j ++) {
            if(temp_q.compare(c[j].getCf()) == 0) {
                foundOne = true;
                cout << "Codice fiscale gia' presente! Inseriscine uno nuovo: " << endl;
                cin >> temp_q;
                while(!CF_Corretto(temp_q)){
                    cout << "Codice Fiscale Errato" << endl;
                    cout << "Inserire di nuovo il Codice Fiscale: " << endl;
                    cin >> temp_q;
                }
            }
        }
    }while(foundOne==false);

    *q=temp_q;
}

namespace indirizzo_non_formattato {
    void stampaIndirizzo(Cliente c) {
        cout << c.getIndirizzo() << "." << endl;
    }
}
namespace indirizzo_formattato {
    void stampaIndirizzo(Cliente c) {
        cout << c.getNome() << " " << c.getCognome() << endl
             << c.getIndirizzo() << "." << endl;
    }
}

string Cliente::getNominativo() {
    return Persona::getNominativo() + "\nCodice cliente: " + getCodiceCliente();
}

int Cliente::getLivello() {
    return 1;
}

string Cliente::getCodiceCliente() {
    return codiceCliente;
}

void Cliente::setCodiceCliente(string s) {
    codiceCliente=s;
}

int Cliente::getNumeroOrdini() {
    return numeroOrdini;
}

void Cliente::setNumeroOrdini(int i) {
    numeroOrdini=i;
}

// *** SVILUPPO FUNZIONI PRODOTTO ***

string Prodotto::getNominativo() {
    return "\nNome Prodotto: " + getNomeProdotto() + "\nMarca: " + getMarca() + "\nStato: " + getStato();
}

string Prodotto::getCodiceProdotto() {
    return codiceProdotto;
}

void Prodotto::setCodiceProdotto(string s) {
    codiceProdotto = s;
}

string Prodotto::getNomeProdotto() {
    return nomeProdotto;
}

void Prodotto::setNomeProdotto(string s) {
    nomeProdotto = s;
}

string Prodotto::getMarca() {
    return marca;
}

void Prodotto::setMarca(string s) {
    marca = s;
}

int Prodotto::getQuantita() {
    return quantita;
}

void Prodotto::setQuantita(int i) {
    quantita = i;
}

float Prodotto::getPrezzo() {
    return prezzo;
}

void Prodotto::setPrezzo(float f) {
    prezzo = f;
}

string Prodotto::getStato() {
    if (stato == 0) {
        return "Nuovo";
    }
    else {
        return "Usato";
    }
}

void Prodotto::setStato(statop s) {
    stato = s;
}
```

**/src/main.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>
#include <fstream>

#include "header.hpp"

#define DIM 16

using namespace std;

class venditeOggi { //tiene conto di tutte le vendita di oggi
    private:
        static int number; //num prodotti venduti oggi

    public:
        static void increaseNumber();
        static int getNumber();
};

int venditeOggi::number=0;
void venditeOggi::increaseNumber() {
    number++;
}
int venditeOggi::getNumber() {
    return number;
}

template <typename X>
string visualizza(X* a, int i){
    string lista;
    for(int j = 0; j < i; j++)
    {
        //controllo se di tipo cliente
        if(is_same<X, Cliente>::value)
            lista += "Cliente n." + to_string(j+1) + ": " + a[j].getNominativo() + "\n";
        else
        {
            //controllo se di tipo dipendente
            if(is_same<X, Dipendente>::value)
                lista += "Dipendente n." + to_string(j+1) + ": " + a[j].getNominativo() + "\n";
            //altrimenti -> prodotto
            else
                lista += "Prodotto n." + to_string(j+1) + ": " + a[j].getNominativo() + "\n";
        }

    }
    return lista;
}

//*** SVILUPPO FUNZIONI CLIENTE ***

void checkCF(string* q, int* i, int* num_d, Cliente* c, Dipendente* d);


/* run this program using the console pauser or add your own getch, system("pause") or input loop */

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    int numDipendenti = 0, numClienti = 0, numProdotti = 0;
    string line; //stringa utilizzata per lettura su file
    string nome, cognome, cf, mail, telefono, indirizzo, matricola, ruolo, settore, codicecliente;
    string codiceprodotto, nomeprodotto, marca;
    char separator;
    float stipendio, prezzo;
    int numeroordini, quantita, stato;
    int i = 0; //contatore
    string q; //string temporanea
    statop t = Nuovo; //statop temporaneo
    int menu; // variabile per effettuare scelte sul menù
    bool exitmenu=false;

    Dipendente *d_pointer = nullptr;
    Cliente *c_pointer = nullptr;
    Prodotto *p_pointer = nullptr;

    //APERTURA FILE DIPENDENTI
    ifstream di("../data/dipendenti.txt");

    while(getline(di,q)) {
        numDipendenti++;
    }

    //ALLOCAZIONE DINAMICA
    d_pointer = new (nothrow) Dipendente [numDipendenti];
    if (d_pointer == nullptr) {
        cout << "Memoria non disponibile per creare " << numDipendenti << " oggetti di tipo Dipendente." << endl;
    }

    di.close();

    ifstream dip("../data/dipendenti.txt");

    //LETTURA SU FILE
    while(getline(dip,line)) {

        stringstream linestream(line);
        getline(linestream, nome, '#');
        getline(linestream, cognome, '#');
        getline(linestream, cf, '#');
        getline(linestream, mail, '#');
        getline(linestream, telefono, '#');
        getline(linestream, indirizzo, '#');
        getline(linestream, matricola, '#');
        getline(linestream, ruolo, '#');
        linestream >> stipendio;
        linestream >> separator; //tolgo il separatore '#'
        getline(linestream, settore, '#');

        d_pointer[i].setNome(nome);
        d_pointer[i].setCognome(cognome);

        //cf = checkCF(cf, i, d_pointer);

        d_pointer[i].setCf(cf);
        d_pointer[i].setMail(mail);
        d_pointer[i].setTelefono(telefono);
        d_pointer[i].setIndirizzo(indirizzo);
        d_pointer[i].setMatricola(matricola);
        d_pointer[i].setRuolo(ruolo);
        d_pointer[i].setStipendio(stipendio);
        d_pointer[i].setSettore(settore);

        /*
        cout << "Aggiunto Dipendente " << d_pointer[i].getMatricola() << ". Livello di accesso al sistema: " << d_pointer[i].getLivello() << endl;
        cout << "\nstipendio: " << fixed << setprecision(2) << d_pointer[i].getStipendio() << endl;
        */

        i++;

    }

    //CHIUSURA FILE DIPENDENTI
    dip.close();

    i = 0; //azzero contatore per inserire clienti a partire da indice 0

    //APERTURA FILE CLIENTI
    ifstream cl("../data/clienti.txt");

    while(getline(cl,q)) {
        numClienti++;
    }

    //ALLOCAZIONE DINAMICA
    c_pointer = new (nothrow) Cliente [numClienti];
    if (c_pointer == nullptr) {
        cout << "Memoria non disponibile per creare " << numClienti << " oggetti di tipo Cliente." << endl;
    }

    cl.close();

    ifstream cli("../data/clienti.txt");

    //LETTURA SU FILE
    while(getline(cli,line)) {

        stringstream linestream(line);
        getline(linestream, nome, '#');
        getline(linestream, cognome, '#');
        getline(linestream, cf, '#');
        getline(linestream, mail, '#');
        getline(linestream, telefono, '#');
        getline(linestream, indirizzo, '#');
        getline(linestream, codicecliente, '#');
        linestream >> numeroordini;

        c_pointer[i].setNome(nome);
        c_pointer[i].setCognome(cognome);

        checkCF(&cf, &i, &numDipendenti, c_pointer, d_pointer);

        c_pointer[i].setCf(cf);
        c_pointer[i].setMail(mail);
        c_pointer[i].setTelefono(telefono);
        c_pointer[i].setIndirizzo(indirizzo);
        c_pointer[i].setCodiceCliente(codicecliente);
        c_pointer[i].setNumeroOrdini(numeroordini);

        /*
        cout << "Aggiunto Cliente " << c_pointer[i].getCodiceCliente() << ". Livello di accesso al sistema: " << c_pointer[i].getLivello() << endl;
        */

        i++;

    }

    //CHIUSURA FILE CLIENTI
    cli.close();

    i = 0; //azzero contatore per inserire prodotti a partire da indice 0

    //APERTURA FILE PRODOTTI
    ifstream pr("../data/prodotti.txt");

    while(getline(pr,q)) {
        numProdotti++;
    }

    //ALLOCAZIONE DINAMICA
    p_pointer = new (nothrow) Prodotto [numProdotti];
    if (p_pointer == nullptr) {
        cout << "Memoria non disponibile per creare " << numProdotti << " oggetti di tipo Prodotto." << endl;
    }

    pr.close();

    ifstream pro("../data/prodotti.txt");

    //LETTURA SU FILE
    while(getline(pro,line)) {

        stringstream linestream(line);
        getline(linestream, codiceprodotto, '#');
        getline(linestream, nomeprodotto, '#');
        getline(linestream, marca, '#');
        linestream >> quantita >> separator >> prezzo >> separator >> stato; //quando prendo separator e' per togliere il separatore '#'

        p_pointer[i].setCodiceProdotto(codiceprodotto);
        p_pointer[i].setNomeProdotto(nomeprodotto);
        p_pointer[i].setMarca(marca);
        p_pointer[i].setQuantita(quantita);
        p_pointer[i].setPrezzo(prezzo);
        p_pointer[i].setStato(static_cast<statop>(stato));

        /*
        cout << "Aggiunto Prodotto " << p_pointer[i].getCodiceProdotto() << "." << endl;
        cout << "\nprezzo: " << p_pointer[i].getPrezzo() << "\nstato: " << p_pointer[i].getStato() << endl;
        */

        i++;

    }

    //CHIUSURA FILE PRODOTTI
    pro.close();

    cout << endl;

    do {
        cout << "Scegli una voce dal menu': " << endl;
        cout << "1. Prezzo senza iva" << endl;
        cout << "2. Effettua ordine" << endl;
        cout << "3. Cerca prodotto" << endl;
        cout << "4. Cerca cliente" << endl;
        cout << "5. Cerca dipendente" << endl;
        cout << "6. Info sistema" << endl;
        cout << "7. Visualizza tutti i prodotti" << endl;
        cout << "8. Visualizza tutti i clienti" << endl;
        cout << "9. Visualizza tutti i dipendenti" << endl;
        cout << "10. Esci" << endl;

        cin >> menu;
        cout << endl;

        switch(menu) {
            case 1:
                calcIva(numProdotti, p_pointer);
                break;
            case 2:
                if(effettuaOrdine(numClienti, numProdotti, c_pointer, p_pointer))
                    venditeOggi::increaseNumber();
                break;
            case 3:
                infoProdotto(numProdotti, p_pointer);
                break;
            case 4:
                infoCliente(numClienti, c_pointer);
                break;
            case 5:
                infoDipendente(numDipendenti, d_pointer);
                break;
            case 6:
                cout << "Numero dipendenti: " << numDipendenti << endl
                     << "Numero clienti: " << numClienti << endl
                     << "Numero prodotti: " << numProdotti << endl
                     << "Prodotti venduti oggi: " << venditeOggi::getNumber() << endl;
                cout << endl;
                break;
            case 7:
                cout << visualizza(p_pointer, numProdotti) << endl;
                cout << endl;
                break;
            case 8:
                cout << visualizza(c_pointer, numClienti) << endl;
                cout << endl;
                break;
            case 9:
                cout << visualizza(d_pointer, numDipendenti) << endl;
                cout << endl;
                break;
            case 10:
                exitmenu=true;
                delete[] d_pointer;
                delete[] c_pointer;
                delete[] p_pointer;
                break;

        }
    }while(!exitmenu);

    return 0;
}
```

**/data/dipendenti.txt**

```
Lorenzo#Bonetti#BNTLNZ96D29B000C#lorenzo.bonetti@mail.com#3386020000#Via Bovolone 1#D001#Supervisore#2500.00#Visual Computing
Filippo#Lovato#LVTFPP96T24B000C#filippo.lovato@mail.com#3937810000#Via Ronco 2#D002#Head of Costumer Care#3000.00#Assistenza Clienti
```

**/data/clienti.txt**

```
Fabio#Livorno#LVRFBA96D21E000C#livorno.fabio@mail.com#3491830000#Via Legnago 1#C001#5
Mario#Rossi#RSSMRA92X34E245S#mario.rossi@yahoo.it#3337788912#Corso Mar Nero 33#C002#13
```

**/data/prodotti.txt**

```
P001#Borsa#Louis Vitton#5#359.99#0
P002#Pallone da calcio#Adidas#30#19.99#0
P003#LG Nexus 5X#LG#3#219.99#1
```

Comment: You need to provide a [mcve] in order for people to be able to help you.

Comment: Why don't you add a debug statement to print the current directory before those ifstream definitions?  Then you'll know.  But also, what PaulR said is correct if you really want to ask questions and get help here on stackoverflow.

Comment: How are you running your program? I expect that your current working directory is not the bin folder.

Comment: I edited the original post adding the whole code and a better description of the problem.

Comment: No, we don't want the **whole code**. We want a small part of it, which is sufficient for reproduce the problem. Read the help page - [mcve] - carefully.

Comment: Please [edit] your code to reduce it to a [mcve] of your problem.  Your current code includes much that is peripheral to your problem - a minimal sample normally looks similar to a good unit test: only performing one task, with input values specified for reproducibility.

Comment: I don't believe `CMake` or even your code is the problem. The problem is the current working directory of your program does not match your expectation. My advise is to print the current working directory in your main before you read your files. That should help you understand what is happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to not use relative paths, as they are relative to the working directory of the process, not the location of the executable files.

You can solve this by passing `${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}` as a macro when building the program, and use it as the root when needed.

Example using [`target_compile_definitions`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_compile_definitions.html#target-compile-definitions):

```
ADD_EXECUTABLE(azienda ${SRCS})
target_compile_definitions(azienda 
    PUBLIC -DINSTALLATION_ROOT_DIR="\"${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}\"")
```

Then inside the program

```
ifstream di(INSTALLATION_ROOT_DIR "/data/dipendenti.txt");
```

Comment: This doesn't work, it gives me this error: 

**<command-line>:0:26: error: ‘home’ was not declared in this scope
/home/filippo/Scrivania/progetto/src/main.cpp:84:14: note: in expansion of macro ‘INSTALLATION_ROOT_DIR’
  ifstream di(INSTALLATION_ROOT_DIR "/data/dipendenti.txt");**

for every word of the path /home/filippo/Scrivania/progetto

Comment: @AllBrokenWings You do have the escaped quotes in the definition of the macro? Exactly as shown in my answer? If you do, then perhaps try `-DINSTALLATION_ROOT_DIR=\"${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}\"` instead?

Comment: This might get it working on his machine but baking his local compilation path into the executable would not be a good solution if this needs to be run on anyone else's machine.

Comment: Thanks @Someprogrammerdude your correction worked!